# Facebook 7.1 Unity iOS Duplicate Symbols

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook

I recently placed the new Facebook 7.1 SDK into my unity project for Facebook login, and in order to use it I have to submit a simulator build to Facebook. The game will build fine on normal Device SDK. However when I switch to the simulator SDK, and attempt to run it on xcode, I get a bunch of duplicate symbol errors, an I'm not sure where this is coming from. I've tried deleting it and putting it back in, and checking for any duplicate files but I can't seem to figure it out. Any help on this would be great. Part of my error log is posted below:

> ```
> duplicate symbol _llvm.cmdline in: /Users/tfurness/Desktop/builds/rocky126/Frameworks/Plugins/iOS/Facebook/FBSDKShareKit.framework/FBSDKShareKit(FBSDKSendButton.o)
> ```
>
> /Users/tfurness/Desktop/builds/rocky126/Frameworks/Plugins/iOS/Facebook/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit(FBSDKServerConfiguration.o)
>   duplicate symbol _llvm.embedded.module in:
>   /Users/tfurness/Desktop/builds/rocky126/Frameworks/Plugins/iOS/Facebook/FBSDKShareKit.framework/FBSDKShareKit(FBSDKSendButton.o)
>   /Users/tfurness/Desktop/builds/rocky126/Frameworks/Plugins/iOS/Facebook/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit(FBSDKServerConfiguration.o)
>   duplicate symbol _llvm.cmdline in:
>   /Users/tfurness/Desktop/builds/rocky126/Frameworks/Plugins/iOS/Facebook/FBSDKShareKit.f
>   ramework/FBSDKShareKit(FBSDKSendButton.o)
>       /Users/tfurness/Desktop/builds/rocky126/Frameworks/Plugins/iOS/Facebook/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit(FBSDKMaleSilhouetteIcon.o)
>   duplicate symbol _llvm.embedded.module in:
>       /Users/tfurness/Desktop/builds/rocky126/Frameworks/Plugins/iOS/Facebook/FBSDKShareKit.framework/FBSDKShareKit(FBSDKSendButton.o)
>       /Users/tfurness/Desktop/builds/rocky126/Frameworks/Plugins/iOS/Facebook/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit(FBSDKMaleSilhouetteIcon.o)
>   ld: 260 duplicate symbols for architecture i386 clang: error: linker
>   command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Answer (score 0):

The problem for me was that Xcode 7 needed to be used to make the build apparently. Everything is fixed with that!